# How to capture string returned from a url called from c++ program

Tags: c++

I want to capture the string value returned from a url. The url is called from a c++ program. For example, the url in a browser address window returns a string value to the browser screen. How to I capture that value if the url is called from a c++ program.

I tried popen but that didn't seem to work.

```
    TCHAR psBuffer[128];
    FILE* pPipe;

    if ((pPipe = _popen("http://xxxx.com/kmver.php", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
         AfxMessageBox(_T("Can't access http://xxxx.com/kmver.php"));
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe);
        CString sVal = psBuffer;

        _pclose(pPipe);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I see how this relates to PHP? The service that creates the web resource you're obtaining isn't really relevant is it? Anyway, `_popen` is not an HTTP client. You need to use or write an HTTP client.

Comment: Why don't you use some http client library ? May be libcurl will help you.

Comment: libcurl is a good lead. Thanks.

Comment: I found a much simpler solution for my situation -- URLDownloadToFile which is a C++ function. A few lines of code, linking with urlmon library vs 6 dlls, 2 MB of additional code and problems with Windows XP.